# Magento 1.9 Registration not possible after upgrade

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, error, registration

We upgraded our shop `from 1.8.1.0` in several steps `to 1.9.3.7`.
Now an error occurs.
The checkout will not be forwarded after sending the registration form. No error message appears.

Comment: Enable error log and paste log here.

Comment: Have you check consol? You need to pass form_key there.

Comment: Can you share the website URL?

Comment: https://industrie-druckerei.com

Answer (score 0):

Enable Form Key Validation On Checkout -> Yes

Enable Log -> Yes

--------console------------

fhydWlG591

load ProductPage ##############

ReferenceError: Translate is not defined            plakat-a1-150g-m-glanzend-4-0:64:13
unreachable code after return statement         product.js:485:8
unreachable code after return statement         configurable.js:291:8
unreachable code after return statement         calendar.js:138:4
Logging system initialised at Fri Apr 27 2018 09:23:26 GMT+0200 common.js:206:17

if Change OptionsValues add this line ################

unreachable code after return statement         configurable.js:291:8

load Cart #################

ReferenceError: Translate is not defined            cart:68:13
 http://mydomain/checkout/cart/:68:13

TypeError: $(...).ready is not a function               cart:292:3
http://mydomain/checkout/cart/:292:3

Logging system initialised at Fri Apr 27 2018 09:27:09 GMT+0200 common.js:206:17

load Checkout #############
ReferenceError: Translate is not defined            onepage:64:13

http://mydomain/checkout/onepage/:64:13

Laden von gemischten aktiven Inhalten "[mythemepath]/default/fonts/font-awesome-4.7.0/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.7.0" wurde blockiert.     jquery-1.10.2-comp.js:3:10127

Logging system initialised at Fri Apr 27 2018 09:28:50 GMT+0200 common.js:206:17

--------end console------------

Comment: sorry I had problems with my ShopCronJob that did not work so I have no errorlogs right now. I try to correct that.